# Problem counting values over fixed amount of other values

Tags: sql-server

UPDATE:

Finally, I got a fiddle together. I believe this makes it way more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee65/1/0

My expected output is:

| Name | Count | SID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VLAN115 | 3 | S-1 |
| VLAN116 | 2 | S-2 |
| VLAN118 | 4 | S-3 |

As you can see there're more VLAN's that 115, 116, 118. But I only need those three and count how many times the occur in COS_AD_memberOf.

Not sure about SIDs as they're unique so would be 3, 2, and 4 times the unique SID value in that column?

---

INITIAL POST

I have three names I want to check ('Name' column; more exist in the table) and I want to count the number of occurrences of them where they match part of the value of column 'COS_AD_memberOf'.

However, I'm only getting the same 'Count' for each of those three 'Name' column values.

```
SELECT COS_AD_name AS Name,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM CacheOrganizationStructure
    WHERE COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN115%'
        OR COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN116%'
        OR COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN118%') AS Count,
    COS_SID AS SID
FROM CacheOrganizationStructure
WHERE COS_AD_name LIKE '%VLAN115%' OR COS_AD_name
    LIKE '%VLAN116%' OR COS_AD_name
    LIKE '%VLAN118%'
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

| Name | Count | SID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| VLAN115 | 166 | S-1 |
| VLAN116 | 166 | S-2 |
| VLAN118 | 166 | S-3 |

How can I amend the query so that it actually counts correctly?

Comment: Can yyou post test data and the expected results? Thanks.

Comment: The issue with your query is that you are using a subquery to calculate the count, but it is not correlated with the outer query. Therefore, the same count is being returned for each name.

Comment: Are you just looking for a simple group by query : `select COS_AD_name , count(*) from CacheOrganizationStructure group by COS_AD_name`?

Comment: That wouldn't work as there're way more VLANxxx than the three I want to count where they appear in the COS_AD_memberOf column plus it doesn't count how often each of the three values occurs in COS_AD_memberOf (which has couple hundred records).

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of window function `count(*) over (partition by COS_AD_name)` or possibly parsing out part of the value before partitioning. Without proper sample it's hard to say what your intention is.

Comment: Added fiddle to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to solve the problem

```
select 
        
       case 
           when COS_AD_memberOfn=1 then 'VLAN115'
           when COS_AD_memberOfn=2 then 'VLAN116'
           when COS_AD_memberOfn=3 then 'VLAN118'
           else 'other' end as Name
       ,c
from (
        select *,count(*) over(partition by COS_AD_memberOfn ) as c
               ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by COS_AD_memberOfn order by COS_SID ) as rw
        from (
                select
                case
                       when COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN115%' then 1
                       when COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN116%' then 2
                       when COS_AD_memberOf LIKE '%VLAN118%' then 3
                       else  0 end as COS_AD_memberOfn
                       ,COS_SID
                       ,COS_AD_name
                       ,COS_AD_memberOf
                from CacheOrganizationStructure
                WHERE COS_AD_name LIKE '%VLAN115%' OR COS_AD_name
                    LIKE '%VLAN116%' OR COS_AD_name
                    LIKE '%VLAN118%'
        )a
        

)a
where rw=1
ORDER BY a.COS_AD_name ASC
```

example:

| COS_AD_memberOf | COS_AD_name | COS_SID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaVLAN115aa | aaVLAN115aa | 2 |
| bbVLAN115aa | bbVLAN115aa | 2 |
| aaVLAN116 | aaVLAN116 | 3 |
| VLAN118ss | VLAN118ssss | 3 |

expected

| Name | c |
| --- | --- |
| VLAN115 | 2 |
| VLAN116 | 1 |
| VLAN118 | 1 |

Comment: Added fiddle to my post.

Comment: I Added  fiddle and edited my code (add  COS_SID based of order by COS_SID desc)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee65/7

Comment: That does work indeed! Thanks. But why is it so much more complicated than in PowerShell? Initially, I though I could simply create an array for the three VLAN's and iterate over them, checking in which COS_AD_usermemberOf the exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PATINDEX` inside a subquery to calulcate the relevant value, then use a windowed count using `PARTITION BY` to get that.

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY v.VlanValue)
FROM CacheOrganizationStructure
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%VLAN115%', COS_AD_memberOf) > 0 THEN 115
         WHEN PATINDEX('%VLAN116%', COS_AD_memberOf) > 0 THEN 116
         WHEN PATINDEX('%VLAN118%', COS_AD_memberOf) > 0 THEN 118
    END
)) v(VlanValue);
```

An alternative is to use a combination of `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to pull the value out.

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY v.VlanValue)
FROM CacheOrganizationStructure
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    SUBSTRING(COS_AD_memberOf, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%VLAN[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', COS_AD_memberOf), 0), 7)
)) v(VlanValue);
```

**You don't have to use windowing functions.** A normal `GROUP BY` also works, and will aggregate up all the rows.

```sql
SELECT
  v.VlanValue,
  count = COUNT(*),
  Sids = STRING_AGG(COS_SID, ', ')
FROM CacheOrganizationStructure
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    SUBSTRING(COS_AD_memberOf, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%VLAN[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', COS_AD_memberOf), 0), 7)
)) v(VlanValue)
GROUP BY
  v.VlanValue;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fee65/14)

Comment: That's interesting as it produces a more detailed output than what I actually need. But it's cool. Thanks.

Comment: Note the final option using `GROUP BY` which gives exactly what you asked.

Comment: One more thing: Trying this with my actual table there seems to be too much data for your third query:

Msg 9829, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: `STRING_AGG(CAST(COS_SID AS nvarchar(max)), ', ')`